# Radeon 560 vs Radeon 555

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, graphics

Planning to buy Macbook Pro 15 2017 model. Is there a big difference between Radeon 560 and Radeon 555. Which should I go with? To give you background, what I shall be mostly using my MBP for:

1. Lot of editing in Photoshop/Photos
2. Quite a lot of Applications being opened (nothing graphical though - Skype with Screen Sharing, Chrome with 100s of tabs)
3. Playing and editing Videos
4. Virtual Machine for Windows running in parallel
5. Dockers shall be running
6. Vagrant shall be running
7. Sublime Text with 8 or 9 projects being opened
8. Xcode
9. Android Emulator
10. Multiple external monitors

What should I choose?

Comment: Based on all that, you should choose an iMac Pro.  Also, a [quick search](http://bfy.tw/HSO6) brings up a wealth of info including this [link in the number one spot](http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-Pro-560-vs-Radeon-Pro-555).

Comment: @Allan he may want a laptop specifically. Also OP, you should get as much memory as you can. Having lots of open applications will use up memory.

Comment: I’m seeing photo and video editing with multiple external monitors AND VMs, which screams nothing-but top-of-the-line. If you can use a desktop, I’d look at a mid-range iMac Pro. If you NEED a laptop to do this on, I’d go with a top-of-the-line MBP, and I would look into the new eGPU support (MacOS 10.13.4) and possibly consider buying one of those too if you can afford it and often work at a desk with many external monitors.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the 560 massively outperforms the 555 in benchmark testing:

[image]

http://gpuboss.com/gpus/Radeon-RX-560-vs-Radeon-Pro-555

And looks like it has twice the VRAM (4 Gb vs 2 Gb) which to me makes it a pretty easy decision.

**FWIW** - I'm a graphically-intensive applications user, and having a GPU with more VRAM means better performance from apps which target GPU processing, so I'm not a *typical* use-case.